# Exception handling for get.chomp with empty input

Tags: ruby

I'm just learning ruby on rails and I'm trying to handle an exception I've raised in the program. I'm following along the tutorial for Codecademy.

This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow, I did a google search and looked for similar questions but couldn't find anything.

```
print "Put in an input to daffy duckify the sentence."
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!

if user_input.empty?
print "You did not input a string with any characters, please enter some characters  or a string and press enter"
user_input = get.chomp
end

if user_input.include? "s"
    user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
    puts"We found an s! ~~~~WOOT!"
else
    print "no s's found in the string inputed"
end
puts "Look at the end string, #{user_input} !"
```

I tried to just press enter in the prompt, inputing nothing and I got this error.

undefined local variable or method `get' for #

Whats a simple way for me to handle this error?

Comment: have you tried wrapping that bad boy in a try/catch block?

Answer (score 1):

Change `get.chomp` to `gets.chomp`  (there's no such method as `get`)

Also, instead of

```
if user_input.empty?
```

You might want to do

```
while user_input.empty?
```

so that you continue to request input from the user if the user continues to enter nothing.